# How to find the return type of a function?

Tags: c++

So `__FUNCTION__` tells us the name of the current function. Is there a similar macro for return type of the function?

Comment: `__FUNCTION__` is not specified by the standard.

Comment: I am writing a script for parsing a C++ code and logging the exit and entry into a function (basically inserting fprintf's at entry and exit). If I know the return type (I can parse it) generically I can print it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you already use a Visual-C++ specific `__FUNCTION__` macro you could look into [`__FUNCSIG__`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0084kay%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) macro - it expands into the full signature which you could then parse and extract the return type. There's no macro that would do that on itself in Visual C++.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't need it at preprocessing time:
In C++0x, you can do use `decltype(myFunc(dummyparams))`, which stands for the return type of `myFunc` (compile-time).
If you now want a string out of that, enable RTTI (run-time type information) and use `typeid().name()` (run-time):

```
#include <typeinfo>

double myFunc(){
  // ...
  return 13.37;
}

int main(){
  typedef decltype(myFunc()) myFunc_ret;
  char const* myFunc_ret_str = typeid(myFunc_ret).name();
}
```

Note, however, that the `myFunc_ret_str` isn't always a clean name of the return type - it depends on how your compiler implements `typeid`.

Comment: @Potatos: Sorry, I should have said during preprocessing. And the string part also doesn't work during compile time. Edited accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Seeing the function itself you can know the return type. After all, MACRO works even before compile time, that means, when you write the MACRO you do know the return type of the function only if you look at it.

If I tell you that you can use `__FUNCSIG__`, even then you do know the return type at the moment you use it in your code.

However if you need to know it in template programming, then I would suggest you to look at : [decltype](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decltype)

Answer (score 1):

C++11:

```
template < typename R, typename ...Args >
char const* FunctionReturnTypeAsString( R foo(Args...) ) {
  return typeid(R).name()
}
```